# Intellij doesn't build classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build, kotlin

I've got multi-module project in gradle in Intellij.
Everything was working fine long time but now for not apparent reason
IntelliJ run configuration doesn't build classes.

As always I create run configurations by ctrl+shift+F10, wchich by default add "Make" to Before launch, however it doesn't build because I get ClassNotFoundException on main class.

I solved it temporarily by adding gradle task build to "Before launch", but it is irritating since I have to do it each time I create run configuration.

Is there a way to fix it?

PS. Tested on different versions 15.0.x - 16 EAP

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by some mistake you have deleted the output path in module settings?
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-compiler-output.html

Comment: Checked. It's not that.